# Postgres Exceptions

Tags: postgresql, exception

I need to port over some Oracle PL/SQL code to Postgres.  This is my first time working with Postgres.

In Oracle, with regards to exceptions, I can have this:

```
    IF v_customer_id IS NULL OR v_email IS NULL THEN
       RAISE invalid_paramters;
    END IF;
```

How is that done in Postgres?  Basically validating input, and if anything fails validation, call a custom handler to perform whatever actions.   From what I have read, Postgres does not support custom named exceptions.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `RAISE` with a custom message and a specific sqlstate constant:

```
--Anonymous block for testing purposes
DO $$
BEGIN
    RAISE invalid_parameter_value USING MESSAGE = 'Invalid customer or email';
END $$;
```

Or you could simply raise a generic exception:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'A generic exception (P0001)';
END $$;
```

You could also handle a exception:

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    --This will raise a division by zero
    PERFORM 0 / 0;

--You can catch a exception with a EXCEPTION block
EXCEPTION
    WHEN division_by_zero THEN
        RAISE INFO 'Division by zero catched';  
    WHEN raise_exception THEN
        RAISE INFO 'Another error catched...';          
END $$;
```

And get more detailed information about a exception:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    error_msg text;
BEGIN
    --This will raise a division by zero
    PERFORM 0 / 0;

--You can get more about error with GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS
EXCEPTION
    --Tip: OTHERS keyword will catch any exception
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS error_msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'My custom exception: %', error_msg;
END $$;
```

I'd suggest you to take a look on [sqlstates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) and [control structures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) for more about error handling in PostgreSQL.

Comment: How does it work if, say in a particular block I may not want to exit the procedure.  I want to catch the exception and do something.   And maybe in another block, I want the exception to basically exit the procedure.    In Oracle, you can code an exception, have it in the last exception handler, and the procedure will drop to where it is defined if that error it hit and not caught in the existing block.

Answer (score 2):

```
do $$
declare
    v int := 1;
begin
    begin
        if v < 2 then -- Validation here
            raise sqlstate 'A0001'; -- custom SQL state, any five upper case letters and/or digits
        end if;
    exception -- Catch exception in the nested BEGIN ... END block
        when sqlstate 'A0001' then
            raise notice 'Here is my exception handler';
            v := 2;
    end;
    raise notice 'Continue here with value %', v; -- Reports that the v = 2
end $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of capturing it in the main exception block, you can add a nested `begin...end` block in the place of `RAISE EXCEPTION` part and raise an exception inside and capture it in the others exception block inside the nested block with a `RETURN` keyword.

```
do
$$
begin
 raise notice 'line 1';
 begin
  raise exception 'raising exception';
 exception
  when others then
   raise notice 'captured in nested block';
 end;
  return;
  raise notice 'check if it continues';
exception
 when others then
  raise notice 'main block others';
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```